# Entity Framework Core(7) bulk update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How to bulk update entities using EF Core(7)?

I do not want to load entities from the DB server, modify properties and update.
I just want to EF generate appropriate UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the accepted answer pointed, Entity Framework Core doesn't support to updates directly in the database yet.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

However, EF+ already supports **Query Batch Update** without loading entities in the context (Support: EF Core, EF6, EF5)

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.

// UPDATE all users inactive for 2 years
ctx.Users.Where(x => x.LastLoginDate < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2))
         .Update(x => new User() { IsSoftDeleted = 1 });
```

Wiki: [Entity Framework Batch Update](http://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update)

Answer (score 3):

This is the EF7 [ExecuteUpdateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalqueryableextensions.executeupdateasync?view=efcore-7.0) syntax:

```cs
var updatedColumns = 
    await
    context
    .Blog
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(p => p.SetProperty(s => s.Title, s => "Wow"));
```

Learn more about bulk operations at *[What's new on EF7, ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete (Bulk updates)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates)* doc.

Answer (score 1):

It is released in efcore 7

```cs
await context.Blogs.ExecuteUpdateAsync(
    s => s.SetProperty(b => b.Name, b => b.Name + " *Featured!*"));
```

Generates the appropriate:

```sql
UPDATE [b]
    SET [b].[Name] = [b].[Name] + N' *Featured!*'
FROM [Blogs] AS [b]
```

Examples got from official [dos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#basic-executeupdate-examples).

Comment: What about multiple properties of a table at once?

Comment: @pantonis try: `await context.Blogs.ExecuteUpdateAsync(
    s =>{ s.SetProperty(b => b.Name, b => "1");  s.SetProperty(b => b.Age, b => 36); });`

Answer (score 0):

At the day I am posting this answer, with the information in my possession, it looks like it is a `work in progress`

See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/795

> EF does not provide a batch update mechanism. A proposal is below.
>   Context.Customers.Update().Where.( c => c.CustType ==“New”).Set( x =>
>   x.CreditLimit=0)
>
> Will you consider this feature? More details here:
>   https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/52

Comment: I see, strange I did not google that by myself, tried a lot.