# Update one column and set all values to 1 using Entity Framework

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

how does one update 1 column to set the value to one for all rows, so my table has three columns customerno,name,doneflag, I want to set the Doneflag to 1 for all,currently i have 8 rows in my table and all have a value of 0 as Doneflag, I want to do one update to set the doneflag for all rows to 1 using entity framework, this is simple using Mysql as it would be:

```
update myDB.Customer
 set doneflag = 0;
```

I tried this but does not work;

```
context.Customer.Add(x => x.Doneflag = 1);
```

Comment: https://entityframework-plus.net/ef-core-batch-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the existing records, modify them and then save the changes, e.g.

```
var notYetDoneCustomers = await context.Customers.Where(c => c.DoneFlag == 0).ToListAsync();

foreach(var cust in notYetDoneCustomers) {
    cust.DoneFlag = 1;
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard entity framework flow is

- Load data
- Modify it
- Save changes

For bulk updates, you have several options:

- Use the standard flow
- Use an add-on library, see: [Entity Framework Core(7) bulk update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37970020/entity-framework-core7-bulk-update)
- Use SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

This topic is covered in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating

> Unfortunately, EF doesn't currently provide APIs for performing bulk updates. Until these are introduced, you can use raw SQL to perform the operation where performance is sensitive:

Using a library like entityframework plus has the benefit, that you stay in a type-safe world that you would loose if you would perform raw SQL.

Answer (score 2):

**Another alternative:**

Install [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (disclaimer: I'm one of the creators)

```
context.Customers
   .Where(c => c.doneFlag == 0)
   .Set(c => c.doneflag, 1)
   .Update();
```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore#why-should-i-want-to-use-it), I understand that the statement above also sets `doneFlag = 0` in EF's change tracker. Is that correct? And if so, is it done economically, i.e. with `DetectChanges` only at the end of the bulk operation? All that would be great of course.

Answer (score 1):

In EF 6 you can use `await myDB.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync` or `myDB.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw` for UPDATE, INSERT OR DELETE SQL command valid expression, example:

```
var commandText = "UPDATE Customer SET doneflag = 0";

await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(commandText);
```

This will update all records in Costumer to `doneflag = 0`. Remember parameterize user input to prevent the possibility of a SQL injection attack being successful.

Comment: IMO, this isn't really "using Entity Framework". It's a shortcut to the database connection that EF kindly provides, but it completely bypasses its core functionality. E.g. any tracked object won't be changed, which may be unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with EF Core 7.0, you can use the ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete methods:

```
await context.Customer.ExecuteUpdateAsync(setPropertyCalls => setPropertyCalls.SetProperty(customer => customer.Doneflag, customer => 1));
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#use-executeupdate-and-executedelete-when-relevant