# Update entity without retrieving first, when the Id is not known but another unique field is

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

If I have an entity called Book with an Id, Title and Price, how can I update that record's Price without retrieving it from the database first? I only know the Title at the time of the update.

Title is guaranteed to be unique in this contrived example.

Normally, I could use Attach(), but that requires me to know the Id, which I don't have.

Basically I want this statement to come out of EF:

```
update Book set Price = "1.99" where Title = "Blah";
```

Thanks

Comment: So execute SQL. EF updates only via PK. Or you can use EF Core extensions which may execute this update via LINQ.

Comment: Some [samples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68636511/10646316)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't some alternative I wasn't aware of for doing this. In this case SQL makes sense. That extension looks interesting for possible future use too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOU can call it  Bach update or delete action in EF.

Here the same code for this work. please see it

[Zack.EFCore.Batch](https://github.com/yangzhongke/Zack.EFCore.Batch)

> Using this library, Entity Framework Core users can delete or update multiple records from a LINQ Query in a SQL statement without loading entities. This library supports Entity Framework Core 5.0 and Entity Framework Core 6.0.

```
await ctx.BatchUpdate<Book>()
.Set(b => b.Price, b => b.Price + 3)
.Set(b => b.Title, b => s)
.Set(b => b.AuthorName,b=>b.Title.Substring(3,2)+b.AuthorName.ToUpper())
.Set(b => b.PubTime, DateTime.Now)
.Where(b => b.Id > n || b.AuthorName.StartsWith("Zack"))
.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it seems like a great extension. One question, can it also be used to update foreign keys on the object? For example if I have Book.Author and want to update the book's author_id field so it references a different Author?

Comment: yes, you can update foreign keys. But as long as there is a key.